# how to use mold linker with bazel and gcc10?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, bazel, mold

[mold](https://github.com/rui314/mold) is the latest modern linker with high speed, I want to use it to replace default `ld` linker when compiling our heavy c++ repository.

I use Bazel + GCC 10.2 to compile, and mold docs provide a `gcc -B/mold/path` solution. However I don't find a way to pass this CLI option to bazel.

I tried `bazel build --linkopt=-B/usr/local/libexec/mold //src:XXX` or `--copt=-B/usr/local/libexec/mold`, but both don't work, bazel still use old linker.

I can ensure mold has been installed on my system, because I can compile c++ helloworld program link by mold directly run `g++ -B/usr/local/libexec/mold`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Peterson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73112909/4928269) can work in most cases, but if you are using an outdated Bazel version such as 0.2x like me, there is a bug for Bazel link stage. The bug leads to user link flags always be overwrite by Bazel default link flags.

To verify the bug, run `bazel build --subcommands --linkopt=-B/any_path <your-target>`, and you will see details about link stage flags.

In my case, Bazel default flag `-fuse-ld=gold` and `-B/usr/bin` always occurs after user flags, so I have to create a soft link `/usr/bin/ld.gold` -> `/usr/local/bin/mold`. This workaround works for me.

So try:

```
mv /usr/bin/ld.gold /usr/bin/ld.glod.backup
ln -s /usr/local/bin/mold /usr/bin/ld.gold
```

Answer (score 5):

Try `--linkopt=-fuse-ld=bfd --linkopt=-B/usr/local/libexec/mold --sandbox_block_path=/usr/bin/ld.bfd`.

(Bazel knows about some linkers such as GNU gold and lld. If it detects, them it will explicitly tell the compilation driver to use them, which bypasses the mold `ld` in `/usr/local/libexec/mold`.)

Comment: Thanks, but how do you verify the executable binary file is linked by mold? I tried args in your answer, but the binary `.comment` section doesn't have mold. I follow as mold doc metioned that run `readelf -p .comment <executable-file>`. Even if I create `/use/bin/ld` soft link to mold, it still does not work. My bazel version is 0.23

Comment: I recommend using a modern Bazel. That version is years old.